# What is the difference between 'to save money' and 'to spare money'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning, difference

What is the difference between 'to save money' and 'to spare money' ?

I thought they both meant "*(to try) to reduce your costs so that you can be left with more money*".

**EDIT :**

Here is a [link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spare) to the dictionary. The 5th definiton as a verb is "**to use or dispense frugally —used chiefly in the negative**". *To dispense frugally* practically means *to try to reduce your costs*.

Whomever downvoted this question would be kind enough to make an explanation so that I could correct my mistake and everyone would benefit from it.

Comment: No, spare money as a verb is not that.  Where does spare mean reduce costs? Please go look up the verb.

Comment: It's right in that dictionary link: *to use or dispense frugally —**used chiefly in the negative***. With the meaning of not use or consume something, "spare" is only used in the negative.

Answer (score 1):

The sense of 'spare' you mention is hardly ever used in a positive connotation.

Eg.

> To spare ***no*** expense. (To spend as much as necessary, regardless of cost.)

> He ***did not*** spare any money when he designed his new house.

These are sentences that would be immediately understood, but:

> He spares money.

Would an awkward and unusual way of saying something. Instead you might say:

> He has spare [i.e. surplus/extra] money, which he is saving for a rainy day.

or:

> He saves money.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What would come to your mind if you heard someone saying 'He spares money'? Would you understand what they mean? In what way is it awkward?

Comment: It's awkward 'just because it is'. There's no reason. People simply don't say it in non-negative contexts. If I had to guess, I'd say it's because 'spare' can be used in somewhat contradictory ways. 'Spare change' is 'extra/left over money'. 'To spare change' would be to do something almost opposite ... to avoid 'extra' expense. So, I might understand what somebody means, but I also might be confused about their intent.

Comment: Some negative constructions simply do not work in a positive context, unless with deliberately humorous intent. As the author Douglas Adams said: "Let us prepare to grapple with the ineffable itself, and see if we may not eff it after all.”

Comment: Haha okay. As you said sometimes you do not end up with a meaningful sentence when you change it from positive to negative or vice versa. And sometimes they are not exact opposite of each other. I was just trying to get a better understanding of the verb.